# Cant move apps to my sd card. Please help me with this as i have 29 gb available and i cannot shift

Tags: applications

I have a tablet with less space. I have an sd card with 29 gb available but I can't move all apps to sd. I downloaded phone2sd but it said no movable objects. If root is the only way please tell me how to root myself. Thank u

Answer (score 0):

Typically this will require root to accomplish. However depending on your tablet, on the newer version of android there is a capability to format the sd to the type for your tablet and will combine it with your internal memory.